# need to set up ros4mat. using Ros fuerte on ubuntu 12.04..... so when i do: rosmake ros4mat i get error

Tags: matlab, ros-fuerte, rosmake, gps-common, buiding-errors

[image: Rosanswers logo]

here is the output i get:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/540b4db592922fcbe585318c6716f7d0

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104271/need-to-set-up-ros4mat.-using-ros-fuerte-on-ubuntu-12.04.....-so-when-i-do:-rosmake-ros4mat-i-get-error/) by [Justin NW](https://answers.ros.org/users/9101/justin-nw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error is missing dependencies. They need to be added to your workspace or installed on your system.

Mathworks now has released ROS bindings http://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/robot-operating-system.html you might want to take a look at.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0